# Allocating memory for structs and its members

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am just getting into structs and allocating memory for them. Now I have some example codes which just work out of the box like the following from "Learn C The Hard Way"

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height,
        int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}
```

So this is what I understand. In the function `*Person_create` the pointer `*who` receives the address of a chunk of memory of the size of `struct Person`. 
`Struct Person` has 4 members, a pointer to a string and three integers. Since the pointer `*who` is of type `struct Person` it should know that it has these members as far as I understand this.

Now I tried to create something similar with some own code. Unfortunately I get segfaults when trying to scanf() an integer for the upcoming variable `int age`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define STRINGLENGTH 30
struct Person {
    char *name;
    char *food;
    int age;
    float height;
};

struct Person *createPerson(FILE *file){
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = malloc(sizeof(who->name)*STRINGLENGTH);
    who->food = malloc(sizeof(who->food)*STRINGLENGTH);

    printf("What is the name of the person?\n");
    scanf("%29s",who->name);
    fprintf(file,"Name:%s\n",who->name);

    printf("What food do you eat?\n");
    scanf("%29s",who->food);
    fprintf(file,"Food:%s\n",who->food);

    printf("How old are you?\n");
    scanf("%d",who->age);
    fprintf(file,"Age:%d\n",who->age);

    printf("Whats your height?\n");
    scanf("%f",who->height);
    fprintf(file,"Height:%f\n",who->height);

    return who;
}

void freePerson(struct Person *who){
    free(who->name);
    free(who->food);
    free(who);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *file;

    if((file = fopen("person.txt","a")) == NULL){
        perror(NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Creating a person...\n");

    struct Person *newPerson = createPerson(file);

    freePerson(newPerson);

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

- So what is the difference that causes the problem?
- Do I need to malloc the members seperately too?
- Is it because the variables are already set in the example code?

Comment: It's option 4 - you're not calling `scanf` correctly.

Comment: as per usual, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is the answer

Comment: [not the cause] `who->name = malloc(sizeof(who->name)*STRINGLENGTH);`  -->> `who->name = malloc(STRINGLENGTH);` :: you want to allocate STRINGLENGTH characters (not pointers)

Comment: As an aside, note that the example you presented from *Learn C The Hard Way* exhibits a serious misuse of assertions.  Assertions are very much the wrong tool for checking for plausible runtime errors; they are for checking for *programming* errors.  If your program ever experiences an assertion failure, it means that your program is wrong.  Moreover, depending on how you build the code, asserted conditions might not even be checked at runtime, so you must not use them for obligatory function result checks.

Comment: Thank you for that golden advice!

Comment: If you know that these strings will never be longer than 30 bytes, there is no need to use malloc in the first place. Simply allocate them statically. Much faster.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(who->name)` is a size of a pointer, which is usually bigger than a `char`. Replacing that with`sizeof(*who->name)` would give you the size of a `char`, which is `1` by definition, so can be omitted in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a segfault becuase you don't pass the address of the age field. Instead you copy it's indeterminate value for `scanf` to treat as an address.

A simple local fix:

```
scanf("%d",&(who->age));
fprintf(file,"Age:%d\n", who->age);
```

While we are on the subject, you are allocating way more memory for the strings than you probably intended. `sizeof(who->name)` is the size of the pointer, which is no less than the size of the `char` it points to. What's more, it's guaranteed that `sizeof(char) == 1`. So the allocation for the string can be completely simplified:

```
who->name = malloc(STRINGLENGTH);
```

Comment: `who->name = malloc(sizeof(*(who->name)*STRINGLENGTH);` would that be fine too?

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies - It would. But do you expect the character type to change? Otherwise I'd advocate for removing an expression that just boils down to 1. But it's up to you :)

Comment: Well I don't expect it too change, but I try to do what I have learned so far. I shouldn't be lazy and care about security. Isn't it better to do so for defensive programming?

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies - Being defensive against user input is very smart. Being defensive against misuse of your API is also very smart. But IMHO, being defensive against something the language specification guarantees is silly :) If you can't trust *that* fact in the standard, why trust any at all?

Comment: I totally get you, since I am just starting to learn to program I don't want to get used to being lazy. Maybe some day I will go more easy on that part. For now I will stick with this. It makes me think more about what I do and so I can really be sure to understand it properly. As you have just noticed that mistake I could grow my understanding even more.

Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies - I'm not saying it's all that bad (it's why I asked the leading question about character types). Do what you feel comfortable with. Just remember it if the verbosity ever gets to you :)

Comment: It is not about "being lazy". It is about being clear and choosing the "best" construct, given all constraints and options. Then `malloc(sizeof(*(who->name)*STRINGLENGTH); `, though not lazy, belongs to obfuscated C.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - I'd agree, except for one caveat. If one was unfortunate enough to program for Windows and the code was littered with TCHAR, then that sizeof is a must :)

Comment: Yep, you got me there...:-)